# I am writing XSLT where I have declared initially "Settlement bank account id" as param

Tags: xml, xslt

This is the value I have declared as param in XSLT.
Now I should define the value in below node.
How should I define this param value?

```
<xsl:param name="wd.Settlement_Bank_Account_ID"></xsl:param> 
<wd:Settlement_Bank_Account_ID>

</wd:Settlement_Bank_Account_ID>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the corresponding XML file look like?

Answer (score 0):

To output the value of the parameter use value-of and reference your parameter with a $

```
<xsl:param name="wd.Settlement_Bank_Account_ID"></xsl:param> 
<wd:Settlement_Bank_Account_ID>
<xsl:value-of select='$wd.Settlement_Bank_Account_ID'/>
</wd:Settlement_Bank_Account_ID>
```